# TypeError: data type not understood in Python fromfile

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to read a binary file using following command:

```
import numpy as np
fid = open(filename, 'rb')
ax = np.fromfile(fid, dtype=np.int32, count=1)
```

This command is working fine, However

```
ay = np.fromfile(fid, dtype=np.char, count=16)
```

gives an TypeError: data type not understood. Any idea how can i read it as character type?

Comment: How does your file look like, what are the first 16 Bytes in hex?

Comment: `dtype = np.str` is for use with characters, depending on what you mean by characters.

Comment: @Finwood its an array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your desired data type is non-existent, `np.char` actually is [a module](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.char.html).

Take a look at the [`numpy` datatypes](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), you could cover your byte representation using `np.byte`, which is a `np.int8`.

Comment: In Matlab u can simply say read as : fread( fid, count = 16, 'char' ) and it will display as in my above mentioned example: A space Ty, so how can i do the same in python if i use np.byte it will give an array of 0 and 1

Comment: Am I getting it right, your file contains 16 _Bytes_ with the _binary values_ 0 and 1, while you want to display these values as human-readable numbers? What output do you get running `with open(filename, 'rb') as f: print(' '.join(hex(c) for c in f.read(16)))`?

Comment: i think i can simply use fid.read(16) and it will display the string

Answer (score 1):

You should use

```
ay = np.fromfile(fid, dtype=np.byte, count=16)
```

instead of

```
ay = np.fromfile(fid, dtype=np.char, count=16)
```

because `numpy` doesn't contain scalar type `char`. More about `numpy` data types you could see [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html#arrays-scalars-built-in). `numpy.byte` type corresponding to `C char` type.
If you want convert array of 16 binary digits to one `int` you can use following code:

```
aybin = np.fromfile(fid, dtype=np.char, count=16)
ay = int(("".join(str(d) for d in aybin)), 2)
```

Comment: In Matlab u can simply say read as :  fread( fid, count = 16, 'char' ) and it will display as in my above mentioned example: A space Ty, so how can i do the same in python if i use np.byte it will give an array of 0 and 1

Comment: @Sulabh Tiwari You need to convert array of 16 binary digits to one `int`?

Comment: @Sulabh Tiwari If I right understand you need some thing like  `res = int(("".join(str(e) for e in ay)), 2)`

Answer (score 0):

So, after I saw your communication via comments, I update my answer as follows:

In your case you should use:

```
ay = np.fromfile(fid, dtype=np.byte, count=16)
```

However I leave the parts of my previous answer here to consider to use in other particular case.

Try `numpy.loadtxt()`.

More flexible way of loading data from a text file.

But if you even use `numpy.fromfile()`, then you have to use the arg `sep`, because empty (“”) separator means the file should be **treated as binary**.

As you can read [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromfile.html), in numpy manual:

sep : str

Separator between items if file is a text file. Empty (“”) separator means the file should be treated as binary. Spaces (” ”) in the separator match zero or more whitespace characters. A separator consisting only of spaces must match at least one whitespace.